# capistrano still asks for the 1st password even though I've set up an ssh key?

Tags: capistrano

Background:  I've setup an ssh key to avoid having to use passwords
with capistrano per http://www.picky-ricky.com/2009/01/ssh-keys-with-capistrano.html.
A basic ssh to my server does work fine without asking for passwords.
I'm using "dreamhost.com" for hosting.

Issue - When I run 'cap deploy' I still get asked for the 1st password
(even through the previous 2nd and 3rd password requests are now
automated).  It is the capistrano command that start with "git clone -
q ssh:....." for which the password is being requested.

Question - Is there something I've missed?  How can I get "cap deploy"
totally passwordless?

Some excerts from config/deploy.rb are:

```
set :use_sudo, false
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "id_rsa")]
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

thanks

PS.  The permissions on the server are:

```
drwx------    2 mylogin pg840652  4096 2010-02-22 15:56 .ssh
-rw-------    1 mylogin pg840652  404 2010-02-22 15:45 authorized_keys
```

Comment: (I wonder if the author's own answer actually implies this has been solved...?)

Answer (score 1):

got it with:

```
set :repository,  "/home/me/git_repo/myapp.git"
set :local_repository,  "ssh://me@mydomain.com/home/me/git_repo/myapp.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I see this issue, the permissions on the server are not perfectly correct. They key will only be used if the permissions on each side are exactly set. I would double check both the file and group and the read/write/execute settings for the key files.

Comment: At one stage it wasn't working at all and I did some chmod'ing, and after this I do have password ssh working.  So I have (a) passwork ssh working, (b) passwords 'git push', working but (c) only 2 of the 3 times 'cap deploy' was asking for a passwork are working?   I've put the permissions I see in the post.  Any ideas? thanks...